# How to get more of a space between a tags inside ul li tags

Tags: css, html-lists, hyperlink

I'm creating a menu bar with ul li tags and the links are to close together how do I get them to have a bigger space between links?

Comment: Padding? An example would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Give margin on li element ...

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Map</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<style>
li{
    display:inline-block; 
    background:blue; 
    width:100px; 
    height:20px; 
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:15px; /* edit this margin to separate your elements*/
}
a{
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:black;
    display:block;
}
.last {margin-right:0px;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tv7pA/

you can remove margin right from last element like top or with jQuery or with css li:last-child, li:nth-child(3) ... but best way is with jQuery or with class coz it is sup. in all browsers